# Neo4j: Get element that maximizes property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For a set of nodes `a` from a query (like `MATCH (a:Type) WHERE ... WITH a`), I want to find the node(s) that maximize the property `a.number`. With `max` I can maximize the number itself, but how do I get the whole object `a` which maximizes `a.number`?

Comment: How can a node maximize a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to return the node with the largest `a.number`?

You can `MATCH` the nodes, `ORDER BY` `number` and `RETURN` only one node:

```
MATCH (a:Type)  
RETURN a ORDER BY a.number DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I thought this would be overkill (sorting the whole list to find the maximal element), but you're right, it works fine.